# dynamic subdomain creation in php

Tags: php, subdomain

With below code i tried to create dynamic sub domain.

```
<?php
//Set the name for your New Sub Domain
$subDomainname="testdomain";

//cPanel Username
$cPanelUserName="user";

//cPanel Password
$cPanelPassName="pass";

//Main Domain Name
$rootDomainName="example.com";


//Function to create subdomain
function create_subdomain($subDomain,$cPanelUser,$cPanelPass,$rootDomain) {

//Generate URL for access the subdomain creation in cPanel through PHP

$buildRequest = "frontend/x3/subdomain/doadddomain.html?domain=testdomain&rootdomain=example.com&dir=public_html%2Ftest";
//Open the socket
$openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2083);
if(!$openSocket) {
    //SHow error
    return "Socket error";
    exit();
}


//Login Details
$authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;

//Encrypt the Login Details 
$authPass = base64_encode($authString);

//Request to Server using GET method
$buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";

//HTTP
$buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
//Define Host
$buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";

//Request Authorization
$buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "\r\n";

//fputs
fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);

while(!feof($openSocket)) {
fgets($openSocket,128);
}
fclose($openSocket);

//Return the New SUbdomain with full URL
$newDomain = "http://" . $subDomain . "." . $rootDomain . "/";

//return with Message
return "Created subdomain $newDomain";

}
//Call the subdomain creator function
echo create_subdomain($subDomainname,$cPanelUserName,$cPanelPassName,$rootDomainName);
```

?>

Output :

It showing "Created subdomain testdomain.example.com"

but still accessed the url this not working.

And nothing added in cpanel subdomain listing.
.

Where I am going wrong!! Help me.

Is there permission need to be given for server?

Comment: im not 100% sure about this, but is there a token to protect against CSRF on the create subdomain page? If so you will need to find a way to generate these are well.

Comment: But this not showing any error for security token